# ReactJS routing/browser-sync reload on /path produces Cannot Get /Path error

Tags: reactjs, url-routing, single-page-application, browser-sync

I'm building a basic React/Flux application and using react-router-component for the routing,  browser-sync for live reload on build changes, and browserify for dependency injection.

The problem that I have is that when the live reload or any reload occurs on a path that isn't `/` (i.e. `/profile`, `/gallery`, etc...), I get an error message of Cannot GET `/path` (or any route for that matter).

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that it's a single page application and all routing is done on the client.

Here is my browser-sync setup (it's very basic). I think that I might need to add some middleware, but I'm not sure what to actually put in the middleware.

```js
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: './client'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely because whatever web server you're using to serve out your app is trying to actually find /profile or /gallery on the server side.  You need to instruct your server that ALL requests to anything goes to root instead.  Sometimes depending on your software this is called 'html 5 mode'.

I noticed that there's a post on the browser-sync git repo about this with possible solutions here: https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync/issues/204

But the basic idea is to make the server send everything that isn't *.js or *.css to ./index.html (assuming that is your app's entry-point file).  That way the server doesn't look for those routes itself, and it just loads your app which is then free to parse them correctly on the client-side.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using browserSync, then it would be like:

```
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');


server : {
          baseDir:'./(anydirectory)',
          middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
        }
```

Comment: If using Webpack, put the historyApiFallback() middleware before Webpack's middleware